# a required privilege is not held by the client while uploading a temporary registry (C#)

Tags: c#, upload, registry

While I am trying to upload a registry in my registries using the C# code , the application is throwing the error "a required privilege is not held by the client". If I am using the same code on some other machine it is working fine but not particularly on my machine

I am using below mentioned code to upload the registry files

```
Process my_p = new Process(); 
my_p.StartInfo.FileName = "reg";
my_p.StartInfo.Arguments = "load HKLM\TEST C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\NTUSER.DAT";
my_p.Start();
my_p.WaitForExit(); 
System.IO.StreamReader srOutPut = my_p.StandardOutput; 
System.IO.StreamReader srError = my_p.StandardError;
my_p.Close(); 
results = srOutPut.ReadToEnd().Trim(); 
Errors = srError.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Moreover One thing I have noticed that the above code I am using in http based web site, but when I am using it in a File Syatem based web site it is working fine. Please help I am not getting the error.

Regards,
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

You can load [RegLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889.aspx) function directly to load the hive as a subkey. Another API is [RegLoadAppKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724886.aspx) but it works only starting from Windows Vista. Different versions of Reg.exe use the API. How you can read in the description the [RegLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889.aspx) you need have `SE_RESTORE_NAME` and `SE_BACKUP_NAME` privileges and enable these (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717797.aspx). If you are in the Group of Administrators or Backup Operators you have these privileges. One more problem can be if Reg.exe use [RegLoadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724889.aspx) function and you have a local administrative rights, but you start on Vista or Windows 7 a command without admin rights because of UAC (User Account Control).